# Sample_weights Keras model - IndexError: too many indices for array

Tags: python, pandas

I have a rather unbalanced dataset, where I would like to weigh some data differently than others in order to implement my neural network with Keras.
I found out that I can use sample_weights for that.

My code looks like this:

```
sample_weight = np.ones(shape=(len(y_train),))
sample_weight[y_train < 1] = 2.0


history = model.fit(x_train, y_train, batch_size=32, sample_weight=sample_weight, epochs=100, validation_data=(x_val, y_val))
```

but it gives me the following error for line 2: IndexError: too many indices for array

If I print my y_train, it looks something like this:

```
           Ertrag
41799      0.979252
48595      1.000000
50681      1.000000
51678      1.000000
4896       1.000000
```

Is it because of the index column in y_train?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: only a simple trial... did you try to transform from pandas to np.array your y?

Comment: yeah I just did y_train=y_train.to_numpy().... it still does not work

Comment: Also y_train.flatten() to get it into a 1D array would not work ;(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error might be caused by the difference in dimension of the y_train and sample_weight. Here's an idea for troubleshooting:

1. Print and check the length of y_train (`len(y_train)`) and see if the returned shape is what you expect
2. Print and check the length of sample_weight (`len(sample_weight)`)
3. The output of (1) and (2) should be the same for `sample_weight[y_train < 1] = 2.0` to work

Comment: Yeah, I was able to flatten my array to 1D - now it works :)